# Importing documents including headers with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a long template file, in which I need to import other template documents to be filled out. Each small template has a unique header with ActiveX labels, which I want to manipulate from the main file after importing, so all the titles in the headers for the different sections are defined by the main document. Each small template should import together with its header, as that is where their version number is tracked.

I noticed some inconsistency. For example one template only has a table, and the header does not get imported either by doing it through VBA, copying manually, or using the insert:object tool.
On the other hand a longer template with paragraphs and headings does bring its own header with either of the previously mentioned methods.

I tried giving the table template its own heading, but that doesn't change the issue.

Does anyone know why it handles the templates differently, and if there is a way to force import headers?

For reference codes I use to import based on the import tool:

```
Range.InsertFile FileName := ...
```

or by opening the document and selecting all contents:

```
docImport.Range.Copy
docTarget.Range.Paste
```

Comment: Please, show us what code you use. Then, what do you mean by "importing"? Please, better describe what you really try accomplishing.

Comment: You might also find https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html helpful.

Comment: I've added the code samples that I tried for the import. Target range is defined by bookmarks, but since that is not the issue, I left only the relevant parts in. As for what I am trying to accomplish is to import each (sub)template into the main file together with their headers and ActiveX labels in their headers for further coding purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on macropod's link I managed to edit together a macro which deletes the target document's header, and pastes in the source document's, taking the ActiveX labels with it.
For anyone encountering a similar problem, tweaking that code to separately copy the header seems to be the way to go.